# Static Ip setting in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: webserver, static-ip

Problem in downloading webmin repository key

[image]

Comment: You have a DNS problem.  Have you set your DNS when configuring a static IP?

Comment: please add the output of `ifconfig` to your question

Comment: Nick ill uploading details in comments